# Google Analytics doesn't split data view into individual domains

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I have multiple domains (like domainA.com, domainB.com, etc.). They are unrelated to each other. Each domain has its own tracking number.

I have created a single GA account named "tws".

[image]

Under "tws->Properties and Apps", I see these different domains.

When I now click a domain in the list "Properties and Apps", the right side "Data View" shows "All Website Data".

When I click "All Website Data", it doesn't show me the data of this website.

I can tell because no matter which domain I click, the data always stays the same.
Even when I click a domain which shouldn't have any visitors, it shows me the visitors of some other domain.

Does anybody see which mistake I made?

Thank you.

Here is an excerpt of GTM:
[image]

[image]

[image]

Now that I made the suggested changes in GTM, Chrome's tag analyzer shows this:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I looked at one of your domain (seen in the previous image).
And as you can see in the images below, you're sending hit analytics to all your properties... so I suggest you to review the configuration of your GTM and send hits to the right domain.

Solutions:

PREFERRED: use a lookup table to send hits to correct Property based domain.

Or:

use a separate GTM for each domain.

Or:

use separate Analytics tag in the same GTM for each domain (not preferred but working).

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your message. I have added a screenshot of GTM for the URL you mentioned. Would you mind removing the URL name (written in plain text) from your post for privacy reasons?

Comment: Thank you. I'll test your lookup table suggestion tomorrow, unfortunately I can only do this tomorrow.

Comment: I removed your url from my answer.
Anyway I added more details to my reply that confirm.
show the contents of yours {{osk}} variable, surely that will give the answer (this variable should be the lookup table).
Let me know :)

Comment: Thank you for the hint. I have added another screenshot that shows the definition of the variable {{osk}}.

Comment: I need to leave the house now. But if you have any idea where I might have gone wrong, please tell me!! I will test it tomorrow again and check the spot that you mentioned. Gracie!

Comment: The problem is definitely what I have described to you, tomorrow try and let me know, bye.

Comment: Thank you for your last screenshot. With that, you wanted to show me that GA tracks this page with different GA-IDs, right? I have now added a lookup table to GTM (like this: http://www.dashboardjunkie.com/gtm/variables/lookup-table-ga-id), but it's still all the same. I have added a screenshot of my lookup table. Should I do anything else?

Comment: Tracking ID in Analytics tag should be '{{GA Property ID Lookup}}' and not {{osk}}.

Comment: @Thank you, I changed it. However, it now doesn't show me the real time user now. It's showing 0 current users although I'm surfing and refreshing the website. I have added a screenshot of Chrome's Google Tag Analysis. It's still tracking one too much, right? When I click the yellow Tag, it tells me "Same web property ID is tracked twice".

Comment: I think it DOES show the number of users right now, but the "tracked twice" message confused me. Do you perhaps see where this originates from?

Comment: How many Analytics tag have you configured in GTM? I check your website mentioned and you're sending 8 pageview hits for each page... You need only one Analytics tag in GTM.

Comment: I had the same tag defined multiple times. I've deleted them now and kept only one. It seems to work!! Thank you so much for your help and teaching!!

Comment: I'm glad you solved it, thanks for the feedback and good job :)